# Visual Studio Express installed with ReportViewer 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2013, reportviewer

I have Visual Studio 2013 and ReportViewer 2012 installed (incl. Runtime).
Now I want to design a report based on a Dataset in a WinForm application.

However if I click on new report in the ReportViewer control nothing happens.
If I use the Report Builder I can only connect to Server based Databases (SQL, OleDB).

Can anybody help?

Answer (score 0):

Install VS 2013 Community Edition (basically Pro with different licensing)